# How to Sort using NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, sorting, swift2, nsmutablearray

I am trying to sort the **NSMutableArray** with this piece of code

```
let sortContacts = contactData! as NSArray as? [String]
        print("\(sortContacts.sort())")
```

I am trying to convert the NSMutableArray to Array of String but when it comes to **`print("\(sortContacts.sort())")`** its giving me nil

Anyone who can suggest me sorting through NSMutableArray?

Comment: You can skip the `as NSArray` and just use `as? [String]` and then just use the Swift array sort method. It needs a closure that performs the comparison for sorting

Comment: @Paulw11 it shows me nil

Comment: Are you sure that `contactData` is an array of String?

Comment: if i print the value of contactData it shows me this 
**"<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a72e450>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a730e10>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a731170>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a7314d0>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a731830>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a731b60>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a731e70>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a7321a0>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a732500>",
    "<Waev_Admin_4_0.ContactDB: 0x7a7328a0>"**

Comment: @Paulw11 in swift 2 still need to downcast to `NSArray` i think

Comment: So it isn't an array of strings, it is an array of `ContactDB` so your conditional downcast fails

Comment: @tj3n, NSArray has always been bridged to Swift array, since Swift 1

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: You need to determine which property of your object you want to sort by and write a sort closure to do it.

Comment: do you have any tutorials for it? as i am beginner

Comment: @JayeshGyanchandani post the structure of your contactdb object first

Comment: **`class ContactDB: NSObject {
     var park: Int = Int()
     var cont_id:String = String()
     var profile_image: String = String()
     var fami_id: Int = Int()
     var ingr_id: Int = Int()
     var inst_id: Int = Int()
     var stars: Int = Int()
     var points: Int = Int()
     var dob: String = String()
     var address: String = String()
     var gender:String = String()
     var mname: String = String()
     var lname: String = String()
     var fname: NSString = NSString()
    var number:String = String()
    var hasSelected:Bool = Bool()
}`**

Answer (score 1):

The class `NSMutableArray` has several sort methods. You should read the documentation. One of the sort methods is [this one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray/1410745-sort).

By the way: a `!` in Swift code is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

This works, just make sure your `NSMutableArray` contains only string, else use `if let`:

```
let contactData = NSMutableArray(array: ["c","b","a"])
let sortContacts = contactData as NSArray as! [String]
print(sortContacts.sort())
```